# addEventListener detect type of change

Tags: javascript

I don't know if this is possible, or what the correct solution is, but I have 4 checkboxes `class="buttons"` and I want to run different functions depending on if the checkbox is checked or unchecked.

`change` obviously detects both checks and unchecks. Is there a way to distinguish them (javascript only)?

```
document.addEventListener("check", function(){alert("checked");})
document.addEventListener("uncheck", function(){console.log("unchecked");})
```

Comment: For checkboxes, it's much better to use the *click* event rather than *change* because some browsers will not dispatch a change event until the checkbox loses focus (which has unfortunate usability issues).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myCheckbox.addEventListener("change", function(e){
         if(e.target.checked) 
              alert("checked");
          else
              alert('unchecked');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `change` handler, `this` is the element, and `this.checked` gives you a boolean describing the state of the checkbox.

```
my_checkbox.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
    if (this.checked)
        console.log("checked");
    else
        console.log("not checked");
}, false);
```